# AWS API Gateway Lambda with custom authorizer returns Internal Server Error with no error logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Created a simple AWS API Gateway with a single route pointing to a lambda integrated with a custom lambda authorizer.

```
- /
  - ANY (any method)
```

The authorizer integration config:

- Payload Format: **2.0**
- Response mode: **IAM Policy**
- Authorizer Caching: **enabled**
- Authorizer Cache Duration: **300**
- Identity Source: **$request.header.authorization**
- Invoke permissions: **Automatically grant API Gateway permission to invoke your Lambda function**

Lambda code for Route:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return {
    'statusCode': 200
  }
}
```

Lambda code for Authorizer:

```
export const handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
    callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
    
};

// Help function to generate an IAM policy
var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    var authResponse = {};
    
    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        var policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        var statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; 
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }
    
    // Optional output with custom properties of the String, Number or Boolean type.
    authResponse.context = {
        "stringKey": "stringval",
        "numberKey": 123,
        "booleanKey": true
    };
    return authResponse;
}
```

I called the route with the following:

```
curl --location 'https://*********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/' \
--header 'Authorization: Allow'
```

NOTE: I redacted the API Gateway ID.

- Expected: **HTTP 200**
- Actual: **HTTP 500** (no special response headers)

Logs:

- Route lambda shows no logs as if it wasn't executed at all.
- Authorizer lambda shows only logs for the beginning and ending *but no errors* of the request as follows:

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v15 Runtime Version ARN: .....
START RequestId: 69017bc6-b660-416a-93dc-2c2d9d2b655a Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 69017bc6-b660-416a-93dc-2c2d9d2b655a
REPORT RequestId: 69017bc6-b660-416a-93dc-2c2d9d2b655a Duration: 14.85 ms Bille
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you `console.log` the `authResponse` object and update the question with the new CloudWatch logs?